# Lodash set with Typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

we're using Lodash/fp and we're running into an issue with the set function, if we assign a new property or replace one in an object, the type doesn't match the expected outcome. Therefore, validation is impossible.
Example:

```
const obj = { foo: 1 };
const newObj = set('bar')(2)(obj);
```

The type assigned to newObj is

```
const newObj: {
    foo: number;
}
```

We've also tried setting the object type manually like this:

```
interface NewObjType {
  foo:number,
  bar:number
}
const obj = { foo: 1 };
const newObj = set('bar')(2)<NewObjType>(obj);
```

Which assigns the correct type to newObj, but we're not sure if the path or value matches the expected type.
Anyone knows a solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'but we're not sure if the path or value matches the expected type'? Are you unsure that `bar` will indeed be a string and that it's value is a number? Can this object contain anything other than `string` : `number` values?

Comment: Like you've said, the object should only contain `string`: `number` values.
The problem is, even though we specify the `string`: `number` in `NewObjType`, we can still for example assign a boolean to `bar`.
Therefore, we can end up with an object that has different values instead of the ones we have in our type.

The type assigned of newObj is
`interface NewObjType {
  foo:number,
  bar:number
}`
but the actual object could be 
`const newObj = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: true
}`
because the resulting type is not being validated.